# How to flag wrong answers?

Tags: discussion, flags

I recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140064/sql-query-to-get-most-recent-row-for-each-instance-of-a-given-key/39340797#39340797) as *"this answer is dead wrong - correct solutions are given above in other answers"*

This was the reply of the moderator:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Clearly anyone knowing SQL and aggregate functions will know that the answer is altogether wrong. Now my flagging was denied - what am I doing wrong? :-)

Comment: flags aren't for pointing out inaccuracies. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: downvoting hurt my rep. score - what is the alternative?

Comment: Downvote, and don't worry about a measely 1 rep.

Comment: why is that better than remove dead wrong clutter?

Comment: thats... what downvoting accomplishes. When we all use votes appropriately.

Comment: `what am I doing wrong?` You're not reading the message that the moderator sent when declining your flag, because it tells you exactly why you shouldn't be flagging posts for this reason.

Comment: to be clear, downvoting an answer even hundreds of times won't delete the answer, it will just gray it out. But that's a crystal clear indicator that the answer is considered bad, and may attract delete votes from users who have said privilege or from the owner of the answer.

Comment: You don't ask a janitor to correct a professor.  You point out where the professor is incorrect, and those who are among your peers will judge both of you on the merits of your arguments.

Comment: @Will That comment reminded me of Good Will Hunting for some reason.

Comment: @Don'tPanic that's because I'm ***Matt F_cckeeen DAAAAYYYYMAAAAN!***

Answer (score 23):

You don't flag answers for being wrong, you downvote them.

Comment: that is usually not the behaviour I encounter. I see a handful of downvotes or maybe just 1 .. and at times 0 votes.

Comment: People aren't required to downvote, they can do as they like. But if you want to indicate that an answer is wrong, downvote it.

Comment: @CarloV.Dango - Moderators cannot be judges of the technical merit of an answer, in part because there's no way we could represent the diversity of technical topics on this site. On a more fundamental level, you don't want a small cabal of users deciding what is and is not correct. The crowd may get things wrong sometimes, but I'd much rather leave the judgment of correctness to community votes. The community gets things right far more often than it gets them wrong.

Comment: @BradLarson Feel free to post that as an answer, it contains much more info than mine.

Comment: *"You don't flag answers for being wrong, you downvote them."* --- *"You don't flag answers for being wrong, you downvote them or inform them that their answer is wrong and to modify it accordingly"* ;-) and if not, then downvote it. I usually give people time and the benefit of the doubt. 95% of the time they just ignore it, so yeah... leave the downvote and let nature take its course.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I purposely left that out, because often you'll be harassed when leaving comments. But you are correct.

Comment: @Stijn That's how they treat the free help. I wonder how they treat their dog/hired help though(?).